# Make Uppercase of array of object using java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have array of hashmap example

```
[
    {
      name:"Sudeep"
    },
    {
      name:"Sudeep"
    }
]
```

I want to make uppercase names of each object in java using java streams. While using it, it makes the response as

```
[
   "SUDEEP",
   "SUDEEP"
]

(List) string.parallelStream().map(s -> ((HashMap<String,String>)s).get(key).toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Kindly Help

Comment: It looks like you have the answer within your question.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: do you want to keep the structure `Map<String, String>[]` or map it to `List<String>`?

Comment: the code you gave is inaccurate (at least in naming). `string.parallelStream()` makes no sense and wouldn't compile

Answer (score 2):

I have array of HashMap which mean you have :

```
Map<String, String>[] map = new HashMap[2];
map[0] = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("name", "Sudeep");
}};
map[1] = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("name", "Sudeep");
}};
```

to upper case all the values of a specific key you can use :

```
String key = "name";
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(map)
        .map(m -> m.get(key).toUpperCase())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Output**

```
[SUDEEP, SUDEEP]
```

---

If you want to edit the same array of Map you can use :

```
String key = "name";
map = Arrays.stream(map)
        .map(s -> {
            s.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> s.get(key).toUpperCase());
            return s;
        }).toArray(s -> new HashMap[s]);
Arrays.stream(map).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Outputs**

```
{name=SUDEEP}
{name=SUDEEP}
```

---

If you have difficulties to parse your json and get the information here is a quick way how to solve your problem (I'm using [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20171018)):

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.*;

public class Mcve {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "[{name:\"Sudeep\"},{name:\"Sudeep\"}]";
        JSONArray parsing = new JSONArray(string);

        Map<String, String>[] map = new HashMap[parsing.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < parsing.length(); i++) {
            String value = parsing.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            map[i] = new HashMap<>() {{
                put("name", value);
            }};
        }
        //... one of the solution that I already provide
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I agree, what I understand is that the OP has an array of Map `Map<String, String>[]` and want to get the values of a specific map and upper case it and collect the result as a List, but hope that the OP can clarify more his question

Comment: I *believe* that when OP says "I have an array" it was meant as "I have a JSON array", since the shown data is JSON, not Java. It is not meant literally as "I have a Java array".

Comment: @Andreas I add the 3rd answer which parse a Json instead of an array of HashMap in Java

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to fully understand what you're trying to achieve exacty, I assume any key is valid and you don't care about the key as I see no reference to it within the question.
Assuming your inner maps have multiple keys and you want to turn the values to uppercase and omit the keys -> this is your solution:

```
map.parallelStream().map(m -> m.values()).flatMap(l -> l.stream()).map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where map is of the form

```
[
    {
      name:"Sudeep"
    },
    {
      name:"Sudeep"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you are looking for

`List<< Map< String, String>> result = Arrays.stream(map).map(m -> m.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getKey(), v -> v.getValue().toUpperCase())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`